# ANT build- Deleting multiple dirsets

Tags: ant, build, backup

I have added a target in a build file to delete backups that are older than 4 days by using a timestamp:

```
    <tstamp>
        <format pattern="MM/DD/yyyy HH:MM aa" offset="-4" property="backup.deletedate" />
    </tstamp>
    <echo message="Deleting log directories created on or before ${backup.deletedate}" />
    <delete verbose="true">
        <dirset dir="${backup.dir}/CI">
            <date datetime="${backup.deletedate}" when="before" checkdirs="true" />
        </dirset>
        <dirset dir="${backup.dir}/DEV_MASTER">
            <date datetime="${backup.deletedate}" when="before" checkdirs="true" />
        </dirset>
    </delete>
```

However it ony deletes from the first directory (CI) and skips the second.

How can I set it to remove from BOTH directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the dirset collection was skipping non-empty directories. I overcame it by using a fileset for the entire backup dir:

```
    <tstamp>
        <format pattern="MM/DD/yyyy HH:MM aa" offset="-4" property="backup.deletedate" />
    </tstamp>
    <echo message="Deleting log directories created on or before ${backup.deletedate}" />       
    <delete verbose="true" includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${backup.dir}">               
            <date datetime="${backup.deletedate}" when="before" checkdirs="true" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Merge your dirsets.

```
<delete verbose="true">
    <dirset dir="${backup.dir}" includes="CI,DEV_MASTER">
        <date datetime="${backup.deletedate}" when="before" checkdirs="true" />
    </dirset>
</delete>
```

Comment: It doesn't delete anything, even though the CI & DEV_MASTER dirs contain subfolders that were modified 4 days prior to the current date?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `exec` task for deleting first level sub-directories (useful for cleaning a nightly build system):

```
<exec executable="find" osfamily="unix">
  <arg value="path/to/dir" />
  <arg value="-mindepth" />
  <arg value="1" />
  <arg value="-maxdepth" />
  <arg value="1" />
  <arg value="-type" />
  <arg value="d" />
  <arg value="-mtime" />
  <arg value="+4" />
  <arg value="-exec" />
  <arg value="rm" />
  <arg value="-rf" />
  <arg value="{}" />
  <arg value="\;" />
</exec>
<exec executable="FORFILES" osfamily="windows">
  <arg value="/P" />
  <arg value="path\to\dir" />
  <arg value="/D" />
  <arg value="-4" />
  <arg value="/C" />
  <arg value="cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" />
</exec>
```

If you don't need to limit to first level subdirectories, you can use the following:

```
<exec executable="find" osfamily="unix">
  <arg value="path/to/dir" />
  <arg value="-mindepth" />
  <arg value="1" />
  <arg value="-type" />
  <arg value="d" />
  <arg value="-mtime" />
  <arg value="+4" />
  <arg value="-exec" />
  <arg value="rm" />
  <arg value="-rf" />
  <arg value="{}" />
  <arg value="\;" />
</exec>
<exec executable="FORFILES" osfamily="windows">
  <arg value="/P" />
  <arg value="path\to\dir" />
  <arg value="/D" />
  <arg value="-4" />
  <arg value="/S" />
  <arg value="/C" />
  <arg value="cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" />
</exec>
```

If you need to include files too, use the following:

```
<exec executable="find" osfamily="unix">
  <arg value="path/to/dir" />
  <arg value="-mindepth" />
  <arg value="1" />
  <arg value="-mtime" />
  <arg value="+4" />
  <arg value="-exec" />
  <arg value="rm" />
  <arg value="-rf" />
  <arg value="{}" />
  <arg value="\;" />
</exec>
<exec executable="FORFILES" osfamily="windows">
  <arg value="/P" />
  <arg value="path\to\dir" />
  <arg value="/D" />
  <arg value="-4" />
  <arg value="/S" />
  <arg value="/C" />
  <arg value="cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path ELSE del /F /Q @path" />
</exec>
```

It works on Windows and Linux systems. One advantage over the pure Ant deletion is that ant does not generate any fileset and so is possibly faster.